# How to remove angular filter (show all) on specific value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a radio button list and when it is selected I apply filter to list.
My first radio item have value `-1` and I want to remove any filter when that item is selected.

```
<tr ng-repeat="m in model.list | filter: {GoalId: selectedGoal}" >
```

So when selectedGoal is -1 I want to show all items (remove filter).
I tried with filter: `{GoalId: selectedGoal && GoalId != -1}` and some other variations but no success.
How can I make this?

Comment: You could write your own filter that checks the selectedGoal value. If its -1, return everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you would be best off writing a filter function.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

```
    <tr ng-repeat="m in model.list | filter: myFilterFn" >

    $scope.myFilterFn = function(m) {
      return (m.goalId === $scope.selectedGoal) || (m.goalId === -1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that you could try is using ng-show and always update the selected radio burron value:

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in list" ng-show="currentOption!=1 || value==1">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="{{value}}" ng-model="value" ng-click="checkOptions($event)" ng-show="currentOption!=1 || value==1"> {{value}}</br>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.list = ['1','2','3','4'];
$scope.checkOptions =function ($event) {
   $scope.currentOption = $event.currentTarget.value ;
};
```